# update data in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, textbox, edit

i want to edit the data in my gridview however it shows me an error that i dont know how to fix. can someone help me out please? here is my aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID" 
OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
        OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductName">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
             ErrorMessage="Invalid" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
            ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z ]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductDescription">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductDescription") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductDescription") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid" 
            ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TextBox2"
            ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z ]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:ImageField HeaderText ="ProductImage" DataImageUrlField="ProductImage" SortExpression="ProductImage" ControlStyle-Width ="10">

        <ControlStyle Width="50px"></ControlStyle>

        </asp:ImageField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductQuantity">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductQuantity") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductQuantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid" ControlToValidate="TextBox3"
            ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression=^[0-9]*$></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductPrice">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductPrice") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductPrice") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid" ControlToValidate="TextBox4"
            ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression=^[0-9]*$></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
    <%--<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />--%>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdel" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" 
        OnClientClick="return confirm('Confirm Delete?');"></asp:LinkButton>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />

        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

here is my code behind:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //Finding the controls from Gridview for the row which is going to update  
        //Label id = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_ID") as Label;
        int userid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        TextBox ProductName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
        TextBox ProductDescription = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox2") as TextBox;
        TextBox ProductQuantity = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox3") as TextBox;
        TextBox ProductPrice = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox4") as TextBox;
        conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=Authorship;Integrated Security =True");
        conn.Open();
        //updating the record  
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Products set ProductName='" + ProductName.Text + "',ProductDescription='" + ProductDescription.Text + "',ProductQuantity='" + ProductQuantity.Text + "', ProductPrice='" + ProductPrice + "' where ProductID='" + userid + "'", conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        //Setting the EditIndex property to -1 to cancel the Edit mode in Gridview  
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        //Call ShowData method for displaying updated data  
        gvbind(); 
}
```

when i try to edit the data it shows me :

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to data type int.



Line 64:             //updating the record  
Line 65:             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Products set ProductName='" + ProductName.Text + "',ProductDescription='" + ProductDescription.Text + "',ProductQuantity='" + ProductQuantity.Text + "', ProductPrice='" + ProductPrice + "' where ProductID='" + userid + "'", conn);
Line 66:             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 67:             conn.Close();
Line 68:             //Setting the EditIndex property to -1 to cancel the Edit mode in Gridview
```

Comment: Perhaps telling us what the error is might give us some clue?

Comment: here , Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write **Convert.ToInt32(ProductPrice.Text)** instead of **ProductPrice** in your query.
like this`

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Products set ProductName='" + ProductName.Text + "',ProductDescription='" + ProductDescription.Text + "',ProductQuantity='" + ProductQuantity.Text + "', ProductPrice='" + Convert.ToInt32(ProductPrice.Text) + "' where ProductID='" + userid + "'", conn);
```